# How can I find good classical music concerts in Vienna?

Tags: tourist-traps, vienna, music

I am looking for good concerts in Vienna. I heard there are a lot of tourist traps around. Specially from sellers in the street "dressed up as Mozart". I heard from a friend that went there, and knows about music, that these performances aren't bad but the prices are clearly inflated for what you're going to see.

Of course I could just go to the Opera or any other recognized concert hall but I am looking for smaller and possibly cheaper concert halls with high quality standards.

As far as I know it's difficult to avoid these tourist traps since sometimes they even come listed in the city cultural agenda.

Are there places/websites with reliable information?

[image: ticket seller vienna]

Comment: _"bad but the prices are clearly inflated for what you're going to see"_ shouldn't that say "for what you're goin to hear"?

Comment: @NicholasB I went to one of these once, reluctantly, at the suggestion of my traveling companion. The venue was historically interesting (probably justifying any price inflation, though I do not remember the price).  So it was also about what one saw in addition to what one heard. Regarding the latter, the performance was (to my great surprise) far better than "good"; it was excellent.

Comment: @NicolasB I think see is a good term. We got, music, but I also apreciate looking at the technique. But there were also a couple of dance moments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For classical music you cannot really go wrong with the two main concert halls (the [Musikverein](http://www.musikverein.at) and the [Konzerthaus](http://konzerthaus.at/home_e)) and the two main opera houses (the [State Opera](http://www.wiener-staatsoper.at/Content.Node/home/Startseite-Content.en.php) and the [Volksoper](http://www.volksoper.at/Content.Node2/index.php)). The concert halls also offer good non-classical music — the Konzerthaus in particular offers great Jazz and World Music performances.

Tickets are actually usually pretty affordable, especially if don't care too much about the view. The acoustics are pretty good in all the venues (the "Große Musikvereinssaal" in particular is famous for its acoustics).

If you are on a budget there is one important thing to know about the Viennese music halls and opera houses: they all have "Stehplätze" (standing places) for about 5-10 Euro (I'm not sure about the Konzerthaus, but I checked the others). They are usually located in the very back, but you can still hear the music very well there. The State Opera has standing places on several levels and you might get a better view from the ones higher up, especially if you are late and the good ones downstairs are already taken. After the intermission you might even be able to get a seat.

Answer (score 8):

When we were in Vienna last year we went to a concert at the [Wiener Konzerthaus](http://konzerthaus.at/home_e/) which we enjoyed. Their programme is quite extensive and there are smaller and larger halls in the building so you could see a small recital or an orchestra. It's just outside the city centre but easy enough to get to and seemed to be well frequented by locals rather than tourists.

Comment: If you define "city centre" as the first (central) district, then the Konzerthaus is literally across the street from it. It's only a five-minute walk from the Musikverein, or ten from the State Opera.

Answer (score 6):

I've been to two concerts in [Musikverein](http://www.musikverein.at/?lang=en), and while they are no Opera, the experience is well worth it. Prices are reasonable for that sort of thing (in the range of 30 to 70 EUR, if memory serves), and the acoustics in the Great Hall (Großer Musikvereinssaal) are great, apart from the lavish gilded decoration. Dress code is somewhat relaxed compared to high-end classical performances (suits and evening dresses certainly not required, though of course welcome).

Tickets are typically available online, or even from those Mozart-dressed guys you've seen in front of St. Stephen's Cathedral. AFAIR, they charge face value for the tickets, but of course it's better to book them yourself online and collect before the concert.

Answer (score 3):

Jeunesse (http://www.jeunesse.at/) concerts usually offer good value (especially it you are < 26 years old)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid tourist traps I would definitely go for Musikverein or the State Opera. I can strongly recommend planning a little beforehand and book tickets in time rather than fall for one of the Mozart dressed vendors on the streets. The many touristy concerts tend to promise a lot but the quality of music just doesn‘t justify the ticket prices and they are packed with tourists only.

Comment: I'll have to see if I can find the venue I attended.  The performance was very good.  Of course, it might have been by chance that I happened to be there when a better-than-usual group was performing.