# What are the advantages of purchasing early-bird tickets for concerts in Vienna?

Tags: tickets, austria, vienna, music

I will travel to Vienna 15/4-20/4 and I am looking forward to attend a classic concert, not a [trap](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21769/how-can-i-find-good-classical-music-concerts-in-vienna) for sure! I am looking into the State Opera House.

Is there any reason to buy tickets **now** and not when I am there (purchase the ticket on Monday for Tuesday)? What is the trade-off, assuming that the concert will *not* be sold-out.

Purchasing a ticket from now binds me, thus I wouldn't like to purchase one, if the price doesn't change! In other words, is there anything like early bird price for an authentic classical concert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the other answer is helpful, it doesn't answer your question: assuming the opera is *not* sold out, you can get the tickets for the same price on the evening before the performance as now. So there is no such thing as early-bird pricing or something similar.

However, you should buy the tickets now. Even for this week, which is a regular week as opposed to the week in which you'll be visiting, performances are mostly sold out or have less than 20 tickets available (at least according to the online booking system). Given the number of seats, this is almost sold out, and if you want to have a choice or sit together with others, you'll be almost surely be out of luck.

If you really want to be flexible, you could however go for the standing stalls: Tickets for these are just sold right before the performance (although people start queuing up quite a few hours earlier) and are cheap (but you have to stand of course).

Sometimes on the evening of the performance there are people right outside the opera house, trying to sell their ticket. But usually demand is bigger than supply.

Answer (score 6):

Since you will be travelling over Easter I would definitely buy tickets well in advance. Easter is a busy season for concerts and operas. The best performances will definitely get sold out. We have the 'Spring in Vienna' concert festival around this time, for example, which is always a big hit. If you get tickets last minute chances are that you will fall into the hands of Mozart wigged street vendors selling tourist concerts.

[I have done a checklist with criteria for spotting a tourist trap for my blog readers](https://www.vienna-unwrapped.com/vienna-concerts/) which may be helpful.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Great first contribution and thanks for disclosing your affiliation with the linked blog. Hope you stick around.

Answer (score 3):

Reply from the Opera:

> Dear Mr. Samaras,
>
> Thank you for contacting www.viennaconcerts.com
>   The prices are not going to get higher, the only risk is that the
>   event you will want to attend will be sold out by the time you are in
>   vienna. Thas also depends on the concert you want to see.   For
>   classical concerts that take place almost daily, there will be tickets
>   available.
>
> For the State Opera, Volksopera and the concerts at Musikverien or
>   Konzerthaus, we would suggest you to book a ticket earlier.
>
> With best regards / Mit freundlichen Grüßen, ...